# S3ServiceException when using AWS RedshiftBasicEmitter

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-kinesis

I am using the sample AWS kinesis/redshift code from GitHub. I ran the code in an EC2 instance and ran into the following exception. Note that the emitting from Kinesis to S3 actually succeeded. But the emitting from S3 to Redshift failed. As both emitters in the same program used the same credentials, I am very puzzled why only one of them failed!?

I understand most people getting “The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records” exception probably may have issue setting up the S3 key pair properly. But it does not seem to be the case here as emitting to S3 succeeded.  If the credentials do not have read access, it should throw an authorization error instead.

Please comment if you have any insight.

```
Mar 16, 2014 4:32:49 AM com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.connectors.s3.S3Emitter emit
INFO: Successfully emitted 31 records to S3 in s3://mybucket/495362565978733426345566872055061454326385819810529281-49536256597873342638068737503047822713441029589972287489
Mar 16, 2014 4:32:50 AM com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.connectors.redshift.RedshiftBasicEmitter executeStatement
SEVERE: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: S3ServiceException:The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.,Status 403,Error InvalidAccessKeyId,Rid 5TY6Y784TT67,ExtRid qKzklJflmmgnhtttthbce+8T0NIR/sdd4RgffTgfgfdfgdfgfffgghgdse56f,CanRetry 1
  Detail: 
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  S3ServiceException:The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.,Status 403,Error InvalidAccessKeyId,Rid 5TY6Y784TT67,ExtRid qKzklJflmmgnhtttthbce+8T0NIR/sdd4RgffTgfgfdfgdfgfffgghgdse56f,CanRetry 1
  code:      8001
  context:   Listing bucket=mfpredshift prefix=49536256597873342637951299872055061454326385819810529281-49536256597873342638068737503047822713441029589972287489
  query:     3464108
  location:  s3_utility.cpp:536
  process:   padbmaster [pid=8116]
  -----------------------------------------------

Mar 16, 2014 4:32:50 AM com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.connectors.redshift.RedshiftBasicEmitter emit
SEVERE: java.io.IOException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: S3ServiceException:The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.,Status 403,Error InvalidAccessKeyId,Rid 5TY6Y784TT67,ExtRid qKzklJflmmgnhtttthbce+8T0NIR/sdd4RgffTgfgfdfgdfgfffgghgdse56f,CanRetry 1
  Detail: 
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  S3ServiceException:The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.,Status 403,Error InvalidAccessKeyId,Rid 5TY6Y784TT67,ExtRid qKzklJflmmgnhtttthbce+8T0NIR/sdd4RgffTgfgfdfgdfgfffgghgdse56f,CanRetry 1
  code:      8001
  context:   Listing bucket=mybucket prefix=495362565978733426345566872055061454326385819810529281-49536256597873342638068737503047822713441029589972287489
  query:     3464108
  location:  s3_utility.cpp:536
  process:   padbmaster [pid=8116]
  -----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the right keys and in the right order (access and secret)? they might be in the wrong order in the param file. Do you have your Redshift cluster in the same region as your S3 bucket?

Answer (score 6):

I encountered the same errors. I'm using IAM role to get credentials. In my case, it was solved by modify `RedshiftBasicEmitter` to add `;token=TOKEN` to `CREDENTIALS` parameter (finally I created my own `IEmitter`).

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html

Comment: I've sent a pull request for this issue. https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-connectors/pull/13

Comment: Thanks. That pull request helped me out.  I did put up a comment asking you to make the same change to the manifest emitter class.